# overlap an unknown shapefile to another shapefile with known coordinate system

Tags: coordinate-system

I am writing as I have two shapefiles, one with an undefined projection/ coordinate system and another shapefile with a defined one. When I add them in gis, one shapefile is shown in another place than the other one.

I am trying to project them together so one shapefile can overlay the other one; I go to ArcToolbox <- data management tools <-Project and Transformations <- Define Projection; As input I was adding the undefined shapefile and then I defined as output the projection as of my second shapefile; then I was using the Project option tool  to project the new saved shapefile, after adding the new saved shapefile, but unfortunately still nothing was happening. When I zoom to the two different layers, they are shown at totally different places.

Comment: Use [Define Projection](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/data-management-toolbox/define-projection.htm) tool

Comment: If you don't know the projection, try http://jhnklly.github.io/projectionuesser/ or http://projfinder.com/

Comment: If you add both to ArcMap and they don't line up, the one with no coordinate reference system is not using the same coordinate reference system.

Comment: Unfortunately, the question that has been asked before didn't help. I also used the Define Projection tool but still the shapefile was not projected.